# Can't get text value

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get "how to use" text value from this [page](https://www.sephora.ae/en/p/nude-obsession-lip-kit-P10043065.html), see the screenshot:
[image]

I tried this css selector but I don't understand why I am not getting the text value

```
how_to_use =  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "How to use").click() #clicking on How to use section 
how_to_use =  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#qqrco4-accordion div").text #trying to get how to use section text
```

can anyone please help me?

Comment: there is no such selector in the html code

Comment: @Psytho can you please help me to find right selector ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. There is no way anyone can possibly tell what the HTML source is, nor what is currently in the DOM when Selenium is running, by looking at a drawn-on screenshot of part of the rendered web page. "Can anyone please help me?" is [not an answerable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) Also, make sure to explain *what you are doing* and *what happens* as a result, *step by step*; "I am not getting the text value" is vague.

Comment: (Also: is it actually necessary to use Selenium to interact with the page and scrape what you want? **Did you try** looking at the page without Javascript, i.e., at the original source? If you do that, can you see a way to get what you want directly?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are scrolling the page before clicking the line

```py
how_to_use =  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "How to use").click()
```

If so, to get the text you want to get you need to improve the locator and wait for that element to be visible.
I have no time to search for better locators there, but the following code is worked

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")


webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = "https://www.sephora.ae/en/p/nude-obsession-lip-kit-P10043065.html"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", 600)
time.sleep(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "How to use"))).click()
time.sleep(1)
content = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.tabs-panel.is-active div').text
print(content)
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/*****/PycharmProjects/test/so.py 
Step 1: Define
Artist Color Pencil:
Matte, highly pigmented, and easy glide pencil to define & correct the lip shape.

Step 2: Color
Rouge Artist:
Exquisite gliding & comfortable texture with moisturizing effect for 24 hours.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to intrude .. but why are you clicking stuffs, when it works without clicking? Here is a working example (setup on linux, just pay attention to imports and code after defining the browser):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://www.sephora.ae/en/p/nude-obsession-lip-kit-P10043065.html'
browser.get(url)
how_to_use_text = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text() = 'How to use']/ancestor::a/following-sibling::div")))
print(how_to_use_text.text)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
Step 1: Define
Artist Color Pencil:
Matte, highly pigmented, and easy glide pencil to define & correct the lip shape.

Step 2: Color
Rouge Artist:
Exquisite gliding & comfortable texture with moisturizing effect for 24 hours.
```

Comment: Without scrolling your code fails on timeout.

Comment: And even with scrolling. The locator you using here - element not becomes clickable

Comment: It doesn't @Prophet :) I tested it, I even made the window smaller to make sure it works, and it does. No clicking, no scrolling. Just a huge outlet within Cite D'Europe, right after you get off the ferry .. but I'm digressing. It works. Maybe a more kosher way would have been to use `presence_of_element_located` instead of clickable. But it works as well.

Comment: I tested it on my side

Comment: And? Does it fail on a Win system? My working setup is selenium==4.4.0, Chrome version 105.0.5195.102

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 / Chrome / PyCharm.

Comment: I'm running stuffs on a linux machine, and test it in Jupyter notebook. There could be many reasons it would work on one machine and fail on another. Curious if it works on OP's machine (he probably left the building).

Comment: Welcome @Prophet . Still curious why it doesn't work on your system. Are you up to date with Selenium, chromedriver & chrome? Or are you **more** up to date than I am?

Comment: I really don't know. Working with 105 Chrome version, proper webdriver, regular selenium 4 version.